# Paypal IPN not working after upgrade from Wordpress 4.7.9

Tags: wordpress, paypal, ipn

After upgrading from 4.7.9 to 4.7.10 and later, the paypal standard IPN has stopped updating and shows an http 404 error.  The url appears to be cut off after the ipn number: wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/payment/ipn/1& and no ipn transactions are being stored in the database.  I think this may be related to CRM-19570.  Has anyone else experienced this?